# Express.js: No Such file or directory

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, fedora

I installed node with `apt-get install nodejs`. Then I installed npm with `apt-get install npm`. Now when I try to run `express` I get

```
$ express 
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

There are two package in Ubuntu that have similar names, *node* and *nodejs*.

`node` does this,

> Description-en: Amateur Packet Radio Node program. The node program accepts TCP/IP and packet radio network connections and presents users with an interface that allows them to make gateway connections to remote hosts using a variety of amateur radio protocols.

`nodejs` does this,

> Description-en: Node.js event-based server-side javascript engine Node.js is similar in design to and influenced by systems like Ruby's Event Machine or Python's Twisted. It takes the event model a bit further - it presents the event loop as a language construct instead of as a library. Node.js is bundled with several useful libraries to handle server tasks : System, Events, Standard I/O, Modules, Timers, Child Processes, POSIX, HTTP, Multipart Parsing, TCP, DNS, Assert, Path, URL, Query Strings.

Fedora also follows a similar package naming scheme. Because of this, the binary in `nodejs` had to be renamed to `nodejs` from the original `node`. However, this isn't technically kosher: and most nodejs programs (and libraries installed with npm) assume that the node binary is `node`. If you want to get around this the easiest way is just symlink the two together. If you take this route, don't install the `node` package which handles the Amateur Packet Radio stuff.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

Alternatively, in the case of node, I'd suggest using [`n`](https://github.com/tj/n) and not installing `node`. Just install npm (which will install node), then remove npm, then tell apt to clean it up. To do this, simply run

```
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n latest
sudo apt-get --purge remove npm
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

There are other binary distro managers that even work from a shell script like `nvm` but I personally prefer `n`. Think of `n` like an apt for just one thing: the node binary which it installs to `/usr/local/bin`.

Why are removing npm? We're not. `apt-get --purge remove` can *only* ever remove things installed by the package manager. `n latest` works outside of the package manager. There are two npms if you do this,

1. version installed by the distro (Debian/Ubuntu) using `apt-get`.
2. version installed by `n latest`.

No point in having the distro's older version. And, even worse, if that version works it can potentially install to a different location and have Debian modifications in it that assume Debian install directories. It's better to use either/or but not both.

Comment: good explanation. this is one of the dumbest bugs i've ever encountered... aren't the package maintainers supposed to make sure stuff like this doesn't happen??

Comment: No, you can only have one binary with the name of `node` with any reasonable package manager, however a reasonable distro would realize that inconveniencing many people because of a package last bugfixed a decade ago, make no sense. This is a repeat of git, vs git-core.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this, why do you remove npm at the end?  Isn't it needed still?

Comment: @JensBodal I was wondering the same thing. But i noticed that my npm got updated not removed ultimately. I ran all the commands mentioned in this answer.

Comment: Updated with the answer @JensBodal

Answer (score 22):

you should install nodejs-legacy package which have a link from /usr/bin/node to /usr/bin/nodejs

`$ sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was because in my `PATH` environment variable, I had "~/progs/node/bin/" and the "~" does not seem to be resolved by `env`... replacing it with the real full path ("/home/myuser/node/bin") solved my problem.

Comment: Great! How did you find that?

Comment: By trying all sorts of different crazy things... :)

Answer (score 2):

This solution

```
export PATH="$HOME/opt/nodejs/bin:$PATH"
```

resolved this issue for me (it should work assuming the $HOME variable is set properly).  It also allows me to avoid hard coding the path to my home directory (for example so I can reuse my .bash_profile with different accounts/servers if I need to)

Answer (score 0):

do this in cmd

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
chmod your folder 700 (optional)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: only for bash command running via deployment tools**

**Note:** In remote server, if you can run node command but via deployment tool like shipit server throws like `/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`. Creating symlink will resolve errors.

```
sudo ln -s $(which node) /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s $(which npm) /usr/bin/npm
sudo ln -s $(which pm2) /usr/bin/pm2
```