# Node.js not found

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 10.10, I installed nodejs from source ( ./configure && make && sudo make install ) and all done successfully. I tried to start nodejs CLI using

`node`

it says

`bash: /usr/sbin/node: No such file or directory`

note : i also referred these following questions

[Express.js: No Such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914715/express-js-no-such-file-or-directory), 
[nodejs vs node on ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04)

but still not able to rectify.

Comment: I'm going to go off a limb here and say the file "node" is literally not found in folder "/usr/sbin"

Comment: The solution suggested from the two links is to create a symbolic link from where it is found to where `bash` is looking (in your case, to "/usr/sbin/node")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

never mind, i found `node` in /usr/local/bin/node.

so the following command made it work.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/node /usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: err... maybe it's better to add `/usr/local/bin` to your `$PATH`? :)