# node no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed Nodejs in Ubuntu 12 from source ( ./configure && make && sudo make install ) and all done successfully.

when i run

```
which node

/usr/local/bin/node
```

But when i run

```
node server.js
```

i got:

```
-bash: /usr/sbin/node: No such file or directory
```

I echo my path:

```
echo $PATH
/root/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/mysql/server-5.6/bin
```

/usr/local/bin is in the PATH.

I found [Node.js not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060309/node-js-not-found). the same question. but i can not make it work by "sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/node /usr/local/bin/node" because  "ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/node': File exists"

Answer (score 4):

I used the terminal to manually copy node and nodejs from /usr/bin to /usr/sbin.

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/
```

Mine worked after this.

Comment: That's a terrible solution, but at least it should work. Better to do something that helps OP's machine find them where they live rather than copying them elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked it works at Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```