# lessc returns empty CSS file

Tags: ubuntu, less

I've recently installed `less` in Ubuntu 14.04 but it doesn't work at all.

I've installed `npm` and `node` via

```
sudo apt-get install node npm
```

and then I've installed `less` with

```
npm -g install less
```

Problem is that every time I try to run

```
lessc bootstrap.less > theme.css
```

the output is an empty css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to this problem.

I wrongly installed the `node` package instead of `nodejs`.

After removing `node` and installing `nodejs` I got this error

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I just executed

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

More info can be found here: [Express.js: No Such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914715/express-js-no-such-file-or-directory)