# Unable to create Node.js Express App using IntelliJ or Webstorm on Ubuntu (VirtualBox)

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, ubuntu-14.04, webstorm

I have the latest version of Virtual box and Ubuntu installed on it. I have installed node nodejs npm and express using npm.

I have installed both IntelliJ and Webstorm, but when I create a Nodej with express project I get the following error.

[image]

This error is shown but post that the project is created and the project structure shows something like this, which is empty.

[image]

Here is the project type I am selecting.

[image]

I have been banging my head on this fr over a day now. I tried re-installing node, nodejs, express.

All this same procedure when followed on Windows, works perfectly without any error.

What should I be missing here ? Please help.

Comment: Maybe this is related, node vs. nodejs package problem? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914715/express-js-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Please check that you path to Node.js is correct. WebStorm can execute the project generator with the specified node.